# Cordova-plugin-contacts leaves navigator.contacts as undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

To give some background on my current project - I am working on a phonebook application for employees where there will be a button to create a new contact on the user's device. I am using the following plugin to handle this in my Ionic application:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/

When attempting to access the plugin the way that the documentation states:

```
navigator.contacts
```

I had also tried to access via

```
window.navigator.contacts
```

It returns an undefined error. In the documentation it states that this will only be accessible after the deviceready event is fired - so my code was the following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Testing Navigation Contacts");
    console.log(navigator.contacts);
}
```

I also tried to utilize the $ionicPlatform.ready functionality as done below:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var myContact = window.navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
    myContact.save();
});
```

The exact error message is listed below:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.contacts.create')
```

Any help would be much appreciated, guys. I'm at a loss of what else to try. Thanks for reading!

Mike

Comment: Try to remove the plugin and re-add it. `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-contacts` and then `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts`

Comment: Thanks for the response @e666 - I have already tried to do this. I've integrated the project into our gulp build system and have reinstalled all node_modules numerous times and the issue still stands.

Comment: @MichaelAmato cordova.js file is included in your HTML? deviceready event is firing for sure?

Comment: @Gandhi Hi, yes - cordova.js is included in the HTML file. The "Testing Navigation Contacts" console.log statement is being printed as expected. Believe this might be an issue with the plugin not loading as expected...

Comment: Sounds like the Cordova can't fins the plugin. Check your config.xml and make sure its there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried out the plugin and it works as expected. Have tested the same in device running on Android Marshamallow.

Have come up with a sample cordova app that uses this contact plugin to add a contact to the device. You can check out the sample in my [github page](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Contact)

Since you are facing difficulties with plugins, i have added the plugin folder as well in the sample. You can copy the project, add android platform, build and test the same. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Using your sample I got the plugin working as expected. Marking this as the correct answer in hopes that it helps someone else. :-)

Comment: @MichaelAmato Glad it was helpful. Cheers. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using this plugin. I think this is a version issue but the documentation has not been updated.

This is how I proceeded:

- first import Contacts in your app.module.ts file

  `import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';
  ...
  ... 
  providers: [
  ...
  Contacts, 
  ...
  ]`
- then import classes you want to use in your file

  `import { Contacts, Contact , ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts';
  ...
  constructor(private contacts: Contacts) {}`
- Now you can use you object

  `createContact(name, number){
  let contact: Contact = this.contacts.create();
  contact.name = new ContactName(null, '', name);
  contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField('mobile', number,true),new ContactField('home', number+1,true)];
  contact.save().then(
    () => alert('Contact saved!'+ JSON.stringify(contact)),
    (error: any) => alert('Error saving contact.'+error)
  ); 
  }`

  Here I create a contact with 2 phone numbers. Of course you can use the other functions find () and pickContact ().

Comment: i'm using cordova-plugin-contacts 2.3.1